# Use State Não salva os dados ao atulizar a pagina

Tags: react, typescript

Criei um context para compartilhar os dados da aplicação e esta salvando tudo normal porem quando eu atualizo a pagina o meu estado esta voltando ao inicial

context ->

```html
type Publication = {
  id: number;
  name?: string;
  description?: string;
  photo: File | undefined;
};

type Content = {
  publication: Publication | undefined;
  currentPublication: Publication[];
  createNewPublication: any;
};

type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  id: 0,
  name: "",
  description: "",
  photo: undefined,
};

export const BuildBoxContext = createContext({} as Content);



export function BuildBoxContextProvider({ children }: Props) {
  const [publication, setPublication] = useState<Publication>(INITIAL_STATE);
  const [currentPublication] = useState<Publication[]>(
    []
  );

  // cria uma nova Publicação com os dados : nome da pessoa, a descrição , e a imagem selecionada
  const createNewPublication = (
    id: number,
    name: string,
    description: string,
    file: File
  ) => {
    // apos receber os dados seta esses dados em uma nova publicação para ser enviado
    // validado e enviado para uma lista de publicações
    setPublication((prevState: Publication) => ({
      id: prevState.id + 1,
      name: prevState.name = name,
      description: description,
      photo: file,
    }));

    // insere a nova publicação junto as outras que ja existem
    currentPublication.push(publication);
    localStorage.setItem('Publications', JSON.stringify(currentPublication));
  };

  return (
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-filename-extension
    <BuildBoxContext.Provider
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values
      value={{ publication, createNewPublication, currentPublication }}
    >
      {children}
    </BuildBoxContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```html
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { FeedContainer, FeedBox } from "./styles";
import { BuildBoxContext } from "../../context/buildBoxContext";
import Logo from "../../images/logo.png";

const Feed: React.FC = () => {
  const { currentPublication } = useContext(BuildBoxContext);

  return (  
    <FeedContainer>
      <p>Feed</p>
      {currentPublication.map((a) => (
        <FeedBox key={a.id}>
          <img src={Logo} alt="2" />
          <h4>
            Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing-elit-Nulla-mattis-ligula-vel-velit-scelerisque-iaculis-Nam-mattis-justo-id-orci-commodo-eu-tempus-purus-cursus
          </h4>
          <p>enviado por: {a.name}</p>
        </FeedBox>
      ))}
    </FeedContainer>
  );
};

export default Feed;
```

tudo funciona normal (tenho outro componente que cria as currentList) aparece na tela normal mas quando atualizo estado da aplicação volta a ser zerado

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

A razão disso estar acontecendo é que o contexto não serve para persistir dados através de requisições. Esse não é o papel dele. O papel dele é oferecer uma forma uniforme de acesso aos dados dentro do contexto em que ele está renderizado.

Se sua intenção é manter dados armazenados através de requisições ou até mesmo após reabrir uma página fechada vc precisa usar uma biblioteca para manter o estado persistido em seu navegador.

Redux-persist é uma boa alternativa. Claro que há outras por aí. Isso é só um caminho que vc pode seguir

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist